# iTunes store / Books / Column browser

Tags: itunes

If I go to the *Books* section of the iTunes store, I see the *Column browser*:

[image: Column Browser]

If i try to go back to the standard view (my Command+B or using the menu "View" -> "Column Browser" -> "Hide Column Browser" I am redirected to the main store page. If I click back on books in the top bar, I get the books section again in *Column browser* mode.

How can I get rid of it?

If I do not choose the "Books" section, but instead I click on the small down-arrow near "Books" and choose a section. I get the usual view with the covers and so on.

Comment: Same here, seems to be the standard behaviour for Books

Comment: It seems that it was fixed by one of the last updates.

Comment: @Matteo - You can answer your own question with something along the lines of "this seems to have been a bug"?  Or is there still a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not experience the problem anymore. I am now getting a normal/usual view. Since I didn't notice when it was fixed it is difficult to say if it was a bug or an issue with the Swiss iTunes store.